# Collections.deque() EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, if-statement, collections, valueerror, deque

EOF error is occurring in this step method, val = input().split(' ') value error occurs when I remove the try block

```
from collections import deque
n = int(input())
d = deque()
for _ in range(n):
    try: 
    method, val = input().split(' ')
        if method == 'append':
            d.append(val)
        if method == 'appendleft':
            d.appendleft(val)
    except ValueError:
        a = input()
        if str(a) == 'pop':
            d.pop()
        else:
            d.popleft()
print(d)
```

Input given is :

```
 6
 append 1
 append 2
 append 3
 appendleft 4
 pop
 popleft
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indent the code properly, here try/except don't match

Comment: Indentation in except occurred when i was posing this question

Comment: Yes, but now you can fix it, [edit] and fix it

Comment: >>> 'append 1'.split(' ')
['append', '1']
>>> 'pop'.split(' ')
['pop']
>>> 'popleft'.split(' ')
['popleft']
>>>

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I tested code and I don't get `EOFError` but `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. But I see different problem - when you run `input().split(' ')` then it first read line and later it split it - and if it get error then you run `a = input()` which will read next line, not line which gives error - so yo skip some line. You should run `input` only once - before `try` - and later use the same text inside `try` and `except`. OR you should split it and assing to one variable - ie. args - and check `len(arg) > 1`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 7, in <module>
    method, val = input().split(' ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: how to read the same input when an error occurs in the first place ie, when the method, val = input().split(' ') line of code gets an error for pop as valueerror.

Comment: you should read line and assign to single variable and later split it in `try/except`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem because you use `input()` inside `except` so in one loop it reads two lines - first in `try` and next in `except` - so finally you have less lines.

Error `ValueError` is raised by `method, val =  ...` which is executed after `input()` - so this line is already removed from buffer and you have less lines in buffer. And when you runs next `input()` in `except` then it doesn't read the same line but next line - so you get too many lines in one loop.

You should first read line and assign to single variable and later you should try to split it into two variables.

```
line = input()

try: 
    method, val = line.split(' ')

    # ... code ...
    
except ValueError:
    method = line

    # ... code ...
```

---

Instead of try/except you could first split line and assing to single variable

```
#args = input().strip().lower().split(' ')
args = input().split(' ')
```

and later check `len(args)`

```
args = input().strip().lower().split(' ')

if len(args) == 2:
    method = args[0]
    val = args[1]

    # ... code ...

elif len(args) == 1:
    method = args[0]

    # ... code ...

else:
    print('Wrong number of arguments')
```

Comment: yeah it worked when I read the input outside try/except block